# How to get the ip adress of a database host by Alwaysdata?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

----- **EDIT** ---------------------------------

The reason of this edit is that my first post was not pointing out the right issue. The new post below should be more accurate.

I am using Laravel so I have to know the ip address of my database, which is host by Alwaysdata.

How can I find the ip address of my database?

I already searched how to get it, but found only how to get the hostname, which can defenitly not be resolved into the database host IP.

----- **OLD POST** ---------------------------------

Title: **How to use a non local MySQL database with Laravel?**

I am making a website using Laravel and now need to use a database. I want to use Laravel migrations to manage the database.
So I tried to run the command `php artisan migrate:install` but got an error telling me that database access has been denied.

My database is a MySQL database. I use online phpmyadmin (actually I am using alwaysdata which uses phpmyadmin for databases).

Here is my database config in the Laravel `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_database
DB_USERNAME=my_username
DB_PASSWORD=***********
```

I am sure about the database name, as well as my username and password.
The database port should be right as I checked it, but I can't find the host of my database.

I already searched how to get it, but found only how to get the hostname, which can defenitly not be resolved into the database host IP.

Does anyone know how to use Laravel along with an externally-hosted MySQL database?

Comment: phpMyAdmin has nothing to do with it, that's just a management platform. The hostname should be the IP address of the MySQL server, and the user you're attempting to connect as should be allowed access from any host (not just localhost). FWIW, `127.0.0.1` === `localhost`.

Comment: on what machine ("my mac" v "the deployed application") are you running this laravel app? on what machine are you trying to run migrations?

Comment: Exposing a database directly to the internet (as this question seems to imply) is a bad practice as many hackers scan for such things. I would not recommend this.

Comment: BenM my problem then is to get the IP address of the MySQL server. That's why I specified I work with phpmyadmin because I thought maybe it could affect the IP. AD7six my Laravel app is running on my localhost (I use Wampserver) but my database is externally-hosted by Alwaysdata. Thomas why is it bad practice ? Have I other choice that having my database on the internet (sorry if the question seems stupid but I do not deeply understand how websites work) ? Anyway Nowhere man's answer works for me, I'll use this for the moment and maybe change later if there is a security issue.

Comment: @thomas, if the DB is well administered (which should be the case here with a team of professional DBAs) and passwords are secure enough (which is enforced by alwaysdata), what is supposed to be the problem?

Comment: @MuZak, you never need the IP address if you have a hostname, that's the whole point of the DNS.

Comment: @Nowhereman indeed works fine with the hostname. I was looking for the ip address but I did not have the hostname either so your answer still helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using alwaysdata, then if you go to Databases > MySQL, you'll see a banner on top with the host you're supposed to use:

[image: banner]

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer, then. Happy it worked for you.